# see call stack without adding breakpoint

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can you print a call stack without adding a breakpoint at any time?
Something like console.trace in firefox?

A use case could be that you want to see the calls to a certain js file which you have no idea in what way they are called

Comment: console.trace actually works for me in Chrome ?!  
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoletraceobject

Answer (score 0):

Add `console.trace()` into your code and you will see it in the Console. It's not just a FireFox feature.